# AutoIT WinWaitActive doesn't uderstands that window is active

Tags: autoit

I want to get pixel color from a game and react.
So I have this sript:

```
#include <Color.au3>

Local $pause = False;

$WinName = "Game" ; Let's say there is a game with this name =)
$hwnd = WinGetHandle($WinName) ; Checked handle with powershell and Au3Info, handle is correct

local $res

Opt("PixelCoordMode", 2);

HotKeySet("{F10}", "exitNow");
HotKeySet("{F11}", "Pause");

While 1
   ;WinWaitActive($hwnd) ; The script stops here if it is uncommented no matter if window is active or not
    if ( $pause ) Then
      $res = GetPos();
      ConsoleWrite ( StringFormat ("Result color: %s %s", $res[0], $res[1] ) )
      Sleep (1000)
    EndIf
WEnd

Func exitNow()
    Exit
EndFunc

Func Pause()
    $pause = Not $pause
EndFunc

Func GetPos()
    local $var = Hex(PixelGetColor(5, 5, $hwnd)) ; Only works in windowed mode, FullScreen return some random colors like 00FFFFFF or 00AAAAAA
    $var = StringTrimLeft($var,2) ; Removing first 2 numbers they r always 00
    local $var1 = Hex(PixelGetColor(15, 5, $hwnd)) ; Only works in windowed mode, FullScreen return some random colors like 00FFFFFF or 00AAAAAA
    $var1 = StringTrimLeft($var1,2) ; Removing first 2 numbers they r always 00
    local $result[2] = [ $var, $var1 ]
    return $result
EndFunc
```

Main script should before window is active and only then should try to **GetPixelColor** but that never happens, no matter what I do, i've tried **WindowActivate** still no result.

**a)** - What am I doing wrong ? Or may be there is another way to check if window is currently active ?

So at the moment I start script disabled, and when I activate window manually I press **F11** to enable.

**b)** - **PixelGetColor** only works if game is running in Windowed mode, if it's a fullscreen mode result is unpredictable. Is there a way to make **PixelGetColor** work in fullscreen.

I've tried to run game x32, x64, DX9 and DX11 in different combinations Fullscreen result is just wrong.

**ADDED:**

Now While looks like this and that works :)
Thanks to Xenobeologist!!!

```
While 1
    $hwnd = WinGetHandle('[Active]');
    If ( $pause ) Then
        If WinGetTitle($hwnd) <> $WinName Then
            Pause()
            ContinueLoop
        EndIf
        $res = GetPos();
        ConsoleWrite ( StringFormat ("Result color: %s %s", $res[0], $res[1] ) )
        Sleep (1000)
    Else
        If WinGetTitle($hwnd) = $WinName Then
            Pause()
            ContinueLoop
        EndIf
    EndIf
WEnd
```

**a)** is now solved

**b)** is still not solved. One more thing, topic of this question doesn't say anything bout this question, should add info bout this into the topic or it's better to start a new thread? **a)** was my main question, it would be prefect to solve b) as well but I can live without it. As far as I understood it's much more complicated. What do you think?

**ADDED2:**

As far as I understand problem **b)** can be solved by using more complex code. Here http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/63664-solved-imagesearch-failure-wdirectx-fullscreen-gamewin7/ was discussed pretty same problem. It's AHK and ImageSearch function, but im pretty sure that the reason I get wrong colours in fullscreen is the same. I don't want to complicate code that much and PrintScreen is too slow so I'll use windowed mode and wont be bothering with **b)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

$handle = WinGetHandle('[Active]')

ConsoleWrite('!Title   : ' & WinGetTitle($handle) & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite('!Process : ' & WinGetProcess($handle) & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite('!Text    : ' & WinGetText($handle) & @CRLF)

Sleep(Random(10, 3000, 1))

If WinActive($handle) Then MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "WinActive" & @CRLF & "Scite ")
```

Comment: Yes! That's Actually helps =) Problem a) is solved. Any clue how to solve problem b) ?

Comment: I assume this could be done by using DirectX or Video drivers... I'm searching though the web nothing I can understand or use so far